# Specific c++ pointer/reference bug?

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, reference, runtime-error

I really thought I understood pointers/references in c++ until I got this bug.

**The problem:**

Assigning data to a referenced return value is not changing the data in the data structure.

**What I have tried:**

I am sure that it is a conceptual problem, however upon rereading tutorials on pointers and references I still cannot seem to pin point the problem.

**The code:**

In header

```
template <class directed_graph_type>
typename directed_graph<directed_graph_type>::vertex& directed_graph<directed_graph_type>::add_vertex(directed_graph_type& obj)
{
    // create new vertex
    vertex* v = new vertex;
    v->vertex_data = obj;

    // adding to list
    vertices.push_back(v);

    return *v;
}
```

*Note: As you can see from the function, a reference is returned. This lead me to believe that changing the value of the vertex data in the following code would also change the value in the list structure. However, when iterating through I find that this is not the case.*

In main

```
// assigning
directed_graph<int> graph;
int a = 1;
directed_graph<int>::vertex v1 = graph.add_vertex(a);
v1.data() = 20;
cout << v1.vertex_data << endl; // output: 20

// iterating through
std::list<directed_graph<int>::vertex*>::iterator it = graph.vertices.begin();
while(it != graph.vertices.end())
{
    cout << (*it)->vertex_data << endl; // output: 1
    ++it;
}
```

Class declaration (just in case)

```
template <class directed_graph_type>
class directed_graph
{
public:
    class vertex;

    virtual ~directed_graph();

    vertex& add_vertex(directed_graph_type& obj);
    void add_connection(vertex& from, vertex& to);

    void remove_vertex(vertex& v);
    void remove_connection(vertex& from, vertex& to);

    iterator begin();
    iterator end();

    std::list<vertex*> vertices;

    class vertex
    {
    public:

        void add_connection(vertex& to);

        void remove_connection(vertex& to);

        iterator begin();
        iterator end();

        directed_graph_type& data();

        directed_graph_type vertex_data;
        std::list<vertex*> connected_to;
    };
};
```

Comment: Where did `v4` come from?

Comment: return *v; does not return a ref!

Comment: @Infested yes it does: http://ideone.com/8VWYHU - the function's return type is a reference

Comment: @kfsone sorry, my bad

Comment: Easy enough - that's why I made the example :)

Comment: oops, v4 was an editing error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
directed_graph<int>::vertex v1 = graph.add_vertex(a);
```

Here `v1` is not a reference variable. The returned reference will be *copied* into `v1` (instead of just having `v1` reference the same variable) and thus changing `v1` won't change the original.

Try this instead:

```
directed_graph<int>::vertex &v1 = graph.add_vertex(a);
```